# Question regarding a ring homomorphism.

Tags: ring-theory

I have the following questions. 
I define a homomorphism $\phi:R\to R\times \mathbb{Z}$ by $\phi(r)=(r,0)$.
I can't understand the following:

> 1.) My notes describe that this homomorphism is not onto. but I can't understand why.
>
> 2.) It states $R\cong \phi(R) \subseteq R\times \mathbb Z $. I tried but didn't get this..

Kindly help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Is there any element $r \in R$ with $\varphi(r) = (r,1)$? Is $(r, 1) \in R \times \mathbb{Z}$?

2) What does the image of $\varphi$ look like? Do you by any chance already have a homomorphism $R \to Im(\varphi)$? What does the kernel of this homomorphism look like? Can you apply the first Isomorphism Theorem to prove that they are isomorphic?

Comment: thanks for explaning ,but  $2.)$ is still not clear to me..can you just elaborate a bit more..

Comment: @spectraa Which step do you get stuck on?

Comment: @Johanne the kernel of this homomorphism is $\{0\}$ ,I now don't understand what to do next..

Comment: @spectraa Have you seen the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings?

Comment: @Johanne it states that : let $B\subseteq A$ be two ideals of a ring $R$ then , $R/A \cong (R/B)(A/B)$

Comment: @spectraa We must be numbering them differently. I'm referring to the one that states $R/Ker(\varphi) \cong Im(\varphi)$. Does that one seem familiar?

Comment: @Johanne you mean the fundamental  theorem of homomorphism for rings ... alright then we get $R\cong IM(\phi)$ thanks..

Comment: @spectraa Do you understand how it works now?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

**(1)** Can you tell which element in $R$ maps to $(r,1)$?

**(2)** A homomorphism from a set to its image! What do you think about this statement?